# condicional subscription rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I need help with this, I have a subscription within a 10 minute interval, what I was wondering is if you can put a condition on this interval so that it only subscribes when a condition is met (I need this .date $ enter the interval only when the date is today new Date ()),
If you can help me with this, I would really appreciate it.

```js
private list$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  public readonly list = this.list$.asObservable();

  private date$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  public readonly date = this.date$.asObservable();

  private lastUpdate$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  public readonly lastUpdate = this.lastUpdate$.asObservable();

  creationDatetime: any;
  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();
  private subscripton = new Subscription;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    interval(600000).subscribe(()=> {
      this.date$.subscribe(res => {
        console.log('agenda pro service', res);
        const pro = this.professional$.getValue();
        if (pro !== false && res !== null) {
          this.findByProfessional(pro, res);
          this.lastUpdate$.next(new Date());
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Observable that grabs the latest value of your `date$` Observable every 10 minutes and filters out any date that doesn't have the same date string as today's date:

```js
const obs$ = interval(600000).pipe(
  // takeUntil(this.destroy$),
  switchMap(() => this.date$.pipe(take(1))),
  filter(date => date.toDateString() === new Date().toDateString()),
  tap(date => {
    const pro = this.professional$.getValue();
    if (pro) {
      this.findByProfessional(pro, date);
      this.lastUpdate$.next(new Date());
    }
  })
);
```

- You'll need an unsubscribe strategy: obviously, the `async` pipe is best where possible, otherwise use a `destroy$` Subject which emits in your component's `ngOnDestroy` method
- Avoid putting logic in a component constructor. `ngOnInit` is there for that exact purpose.
- Avoid putting logic in `subscribe` callbacks. Generally speaking, you should avoid subscribing in TS code wherever possible, and all logic should be somewhere in your Observable's `pipe`.

Comment: the `date$` is a `BehaviorSubject` so you can just use `getValue()` while filtering. If you don't want to use the private field tho you can just replace the `date$` with `date`

Comment: Very true. I generally don't expose a `BehaviorSubject` as is: I tend to use `.asObservable()` to avoid issues, so my reflex is to subscribe with a mapping operator. In this specific case, `getValue()` would work, you're correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is how Will Alexanders answer can be improved to be little bit more declarative.

```
const obs$ = interval(600000).pipe(
   // takeUntil(this.destroy$),
   switchMap(() => this.date$.pipe(take(1))),
   filter(date => date.toDateString() === new Date().toDateString()),
   withLatestFrom(this.professional$),
   filter([date, pro] => pro),
   tap([date, pro] => {
       this.findByProfessional(pro, date);
       this.lastUpdate$.next(new Date());
   })
);
```